# Byte array to bool array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to take in a byte [] and convert it to a bool []. I have found a code that places the bool in a bool queue, but I don't posses the necessary skill/knowledge to go from a method that gives me a bool queue to a method that gives me a bool array.

Any help is appreciated!

```
public void TmsTdiEnqueue(int bitCount, byte[] byteArray)
        {
            // New TAP bit queues with allocated number of bits
            boolQueue = new Queue<bool>(bitCount);

            // Fill bool queue
            int byteIndex = 0;
            int bitMask = 0x01;
            for (int i = 0; i < bitCount; i++)
            {
                boolQueue.Enqueue((tmsBytes[byteIndex] & bitMask) != 0);
                IncrementBitPointer(ref byteIndex, ref bitMask);
            }
        }

        private void IncrementBitPointer(ref int byteIndex, ref int bitMask)
        {
            byteIndex += (bitMask == 0x80) ? 1 : 0;
            bitMask = (bitMask == 0x80) ? 0x01 : bitMask << 1;
        }
```

Comment: What is the requirement regarding the elements of the `bool` array? When should be an element of it `true` and when should it be `false`?

Comment: Try following :  Boolean[] status = byteArray.Select(x => (x == 0)? false : true).ToArray();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the source `byte[]` array has one boolean value per bit, you could simply use the [`BitArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray) class:

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
bool[] ret = new bool[ba.Length];
ba.CopyTo(ret, 0);
```

Comment: This works, however, the bytes are reversed. How can I reverse it back? If I expect a byte array with byte[0] = 28, byte[1] = 52, I get byte[0] = 52, byte[1] = 28

Comment: @Ioragi You could use the [`Array.Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse#System_Array_Reverse_System_Array_) static method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectMany` to do this. First, start with a method that converts a single `byte` to an array of `bool`:

```
static bool[] ByteToBools(byte value)
{
    var values = new bool[8];

    values[0] = (value & 1) == 0 ? false : true;
    values[1] = (value & 2) == 0 ? false : true;
    values[2] = (value & 4) == 0 ? false : true;
    values[3] = (value & 8) == 0 ? false : true;
    values[4] = (value & 16) == 0 ? false : true;
    values[5] = (value & 32) == 0 ? false : true;
    values[6] = (value & 64) == 0 ? false : true;
    values[7] = (value & 128) == 0 ? false : true;

    return values;
}
```

Now we just `SelectMany`over the`byte` array, and for each byte we call `ByteToBools`:

```
var numbers = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 5, 255};

var bits = numbers.SelectMany(number => ByteToBools(number));
foreach(var bit in bits)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bit);
}
```

Comment: Anything of the form `foo ? false : true` can **always** be reduced to `!foo`. Therefore: `values[0] = (value & 1) != 0` and so on.

Comment: This can also be improved using iterations, since your code follows the repeated format of `values[i] = (value & Math.Pow(2,i)) != 0`

Comment: @Flater - I disagree with the statement that iteration would improve the code. A loop with calls to `Pow` and then a compare will be more inefficient that a simple compare and assign.

Comment: You could use `for (var i = 0, j = 1; i < 8; i++, j <<= 1) { values[i] = (value & j) != 0; }`